# BUF634 - Rail splitter +/-5 V from single 10 V power supply

Tags: power-supply, analog

I'm trying to figure out how to create +/-5 V from a single power supply (10 V) for analog ICs.

I'm not sure if the pins are connected correctly in my schematics (in the datasheet of the BUF634 there are no pin numbers in the examples):

[image]

This is what I have put together:

[image]

- Is the IC correctly wired?
- What should be the capacitors on the output?

Comment: You can Split voltage Rail, can be achived multiple ways, search for "Split power/ supply"
URLs4: [TI - The top three ways to split a voltage rail to a bipolar supply](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/the-top-three-ways-to-split-a-voltage-rail-to-a-bipolar-supply) [Analog - Easy, ±5V Split-Voltage Power Supply for Analog Circuits Draws Only 720nA at No Load](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/easy-split-voltage-power-supply-for-analog-circuits-draws-only-720na.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should follow **all** the relevant recommendations in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/buf634a.pdf).

You've omitted the recommended 100nF capacitor in parallel with the 10uF bulk capacitor. The former should be very close to the device supply pins. The two output capacitors can be 100nF ceramic and if you use additional bulk capacitors they would best be closer to the load and further from the chip. The 100nF output caps should be very close to the chip.

It would be prudent to allow for the BW resistor even if you end up not populating it. If you find the circuit is less stable than you would like when you perform testing you might find that very helpful.

For testing, I suggest applying various square wave loads at some convenient frequency to the pseudo-ground and observing the voltage on an oscilloscope. Oscillatory behavior, even damped, is a reason for concern. DC loading can affect stability so the state of whatever it is that you are powering may matter. Your options for dealing with undesirably low phase margin include changing your PCB layout with additional spins, modifying capacitor values (and which are placed where), and modifying the BW. Some are easier than others.

Your connections look fine (see final and penultimate sentences below though). It's fairly common to omit pin numbers in example diagrams. This avoids confusion and possible errors (by the user, or when the datasheet is revised to include additional options) if the device is available in multiple packages, which may not have the same pinout (for example, some of the available packages have an extra 9th pin- the thermal pad- which must be connected electrically to V-). If your package has such a pad then your schematic needs to show it for the connections to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the IC correctly wired?

Yes, I would also relabel the V+ and V- to Vcc+ and Vcc-. It might also be better to relabel GNDA as VGND so it's clear it isn't a ground. A virtual ground has limited current sinking capabilities.

> What should be the capacitors on the output?

Depends on what the ripple of the load would be but 1uF or 10uF would be a good place to start.